# Get the total number of iterations until a condition is met

Tags: c#, for-loop

```
for (int i= 0; i<10; i++)
{
    phi0 = phi0 * (L / L0);
    X0 = R * Math.Sin(2 * phi0) * Math.Cos(phi0);
    L0 = X0 * (1 + (Math.Pow(Math.Tan(phi0), 2)) / 10 - (Math.Pow(Math.Tan(phi0), 4)) / 72 + (Math.Pow(Math.Tan(phi0), 6)) / 208);
    if ((Math.Abs(L0 - L)) < (0.003 * Math.Sqrt(L)))
        break;
}
```

Usually after 2,3 iterations the condition is met, but I need a message to show the number of iterations after which the condition is met and also if its exceeds the total amount of 10.

If there is something to explain fell free to ask.

Thank you!

Comment: I only know c# for 1 day. So please excuse me for not know the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the declaration of `i` outside the loop and you can use it's value afterwards.  Remember that the value of `i` will be one less than the number of iterations used since you're starting at 0 -- in fact since you don't use `i` in any of the expressions in the loop, you may want it to from from 1 to 10 instead of 0 to 9.

Note you can also make a small optimization to make things faster. The compiler might do it for you, but you can make sure by storing the intermediate calculation of `tan(phi0)` in a local varaiable.

```
int i = 1;
for (; i<=10; i++)
{
    phi0 = phi0 * (L / L0);
    var tanPhi0 = Math.Tan(phi0);
    X0 = R * Math.Sin(2 * phi0) * Math.Cos(phi0);
    L0 = X0 * (1 + (Math.Pow(tanPhi0, 2)) / 10 - (Math.Pow(tanPhi0, 4)) / 72 + (Math.Pow(tanPhi0, 6)) / 208);
    if ((Math.Abs(L0 - L)) < (0.003 * Math.Sqrt(L)))
        break;
}

if (i <= 10)
{
    Console.WriteLine( "The loop took {0} iterations", i );
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine( "It did not converge" );
}
```

In fact, if this gets executed many times, you may want to carry it one step further and try  computing the powers of `tan(phi0)` in stages as well instead of calling `Pow` each time. I'm making the assumption here that multiplication is faster than calling the `Pow` method, which seems reasonable, but you'll want to test it to make sure. There's also no reason to compute the error bound each time.

```
var epsilon = 0.003 * Math.Sqrt(L);
int i = 1;
for (; i<=10; i++)
{
    phi0 = phi0 * (L / L0);
    var tanPhi0 = Math.Tan(phi0);
    var tanPhi0_2 = tanPhi0 * tanPhi0;
    var tanPhi0_4 = tanPhi0_2 * tanPhi0_2;
    var tanPhi0_6 = tanPhi0_4 * tanPhi0_2;
    X0 = R * Math.Sin(2 * phi0) * Math.Cos(phi0);
    L0 = X0 * (1 + tanPhi0_2 / 10 - tanPhi0_4 / 72 + tanPhi0_6 / 208);
    if ((Math.Abs(L0 - L)) < epsilon)
        break;
}

if (i <= 10)
{
    Console.WriteLine( "The loop took {0} iterations", i );
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine( "It did not converge" );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Move the declaration of `i` outside the loop so it is available after it.

You can then check its value right after the loop. If it is `<10`, the loop exited via your exit condition. If it is exactly `10`, then the last allowed iteration (with `i==9`) didn't meet the exit condition.

Answer (score 1):

declare `i` outside (before) the loop and and you can do stuff with it afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a simple counter:

```
int iterCount = 0;
for (int i= 0; i<10; i++)
{
    iterCount++;
    ϕ0 = ϕ0 * (L / L0);
    X0 = R * Math.Sin(2 * ϕ0) * Math.Cos(ϕ0);
    L0 = X0 * (1 + (Math.Pow(Math.Tan(ϕ0), 2)) / 10 - (Math.Pow(Math.Tan(ϕ0), 4)) / 72 + (Math.Pow(Math.Tan(ϕ0), 6)) / 208);
    if ((Math.Abs(L0 - L)) < (0.003 * Math.Sqrt(L)))
        break;

}
MessageBox.Show("Number of iterations: " + iterCount);
```

Comment: This the way I've thought of, but I was putting the count before the IF.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a boolean variable (`bool done = false`) before the loop and set it to `true` if the condition is met.
Right before you break, print the value of `i` to get the number of iterations.

```
 if ((Math.Abs(L0 - L)) < (0.003 * Math.Sqrt(L))) {
       done = true;
       Console.WriteLine(i);
       break;
 }
```

if `done == false` after the loop, it means that the condition wasn't met in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You basically just need to expand the scope of the variable i, right? This could be done like this:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i<10; i++)
{
  //Do stuff
}
Console.WriteLine("i: " + i);
```

The variable i is still in scope outside the loop, and holds the value that it had, when the loop broke; or 10 if it didnt break at all.

Hope this helps.